# Is it possible to disable Apple Watch iMessage notifications while my MacBook Air is unlocked?

Tags: macbook-pro, messages, notifications, apple-watch, continuity

I know that Apple Watch notifications are silenced while you are using your iPhone in order to prevent duplicate notifications. Is it possible to extend this functionality to silence my Apple Watch notifications while I am using my MacBook Air? I would only like to receive iMessage notifications on my Apple Watch when I am not using both my iPhone and MacBook Air.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Handoff now works properly in Sierra :)